# IF-formula and Conditional formatting not working properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Harvey Goals:
[image: Harvey Goals]

**Goal (Image above):**

1. In box nr. 1, you can see see 5 financial goals for Harvey
2. In box nr. 2, you can see what the generated revenue is from Harvey
3. In box nr. 3, you can see what the true percentages are of revenue vs goal
4. In box nr. 4, you can see the goal percentages, but this time capped at 100%
   if the true percentage is higher than 100%
5. In box nr. 5, is where the problem starts.

**Problem:**

- In box nr. 5, I want the user to focus on one goal percentage. In this case Goal #4, of 98.2%
- So, with a formula, I tried to show the following:
- Goals that were already met: at 100% (Goals #1-3).
- The main goal in progress: to show the current goal percentage (Goal #4)
- And lastly the "locked" goals: to show a "-" (Goal #5)

**Now there are 2 problemens:**

**1. Conditional formatting**

- First the formatting. Whatever I try, it seems that the "-" or any other text like "locked" or "0" or "0%", gets the same conditional formatting as the 100%: green font + strikethrough
- I tried to get the font text to be orange, as seen in Goal # 4: 98.2%. But I can't get it to work.

**2. Mike (Formula problem)**

- Secondly, the formula seems to break down when I use the goals of Mike:
- See picture:

Mike goals:
[image: Mike goals]

- In box nr. 5, the perfect situation would be (Image above):
- Goal nr. #1 would be shown: 47.1%
- Goal nr. #2-5 would have a: - (with orange font format)

Link to the Excel-workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa8vjxebsmlirzy/Goal%20percentages.xlsx?dl=0

Help!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Conditional Format Formula to turn cell font green: `=AND(ISNUMBER(D4),D4>=1)`
- Conditional Format Formula to turn cell font orange: `=OR(D4="-",D4<1)`
- Formula to properly only view the first non-100% result in box 5:

  - In cell D12 simply use `=D4`
  - In cell D13 and copy down, use `=IF(D12<>1,"-",D5)`

Apply the conditional format formulas to the proper areas.  Cell references shown in the formulas are based on the provided sample image, change as necessary for your actual data.

Comment: Thank you TigerAvatar! It works like a charm!:)

I learned from you:
- saw that excel sees 1 = 100%
- so that means 0.99 = 99% etc
- Also never knew about the AND, ISNUMBER and OR function!
- Learned that the opposite of the = (equals) sign is <> (not equal to)

Thank you for the lessons!